# How long to travel from Ireland or England in 1680 to Plymouth in the Massachusetts Bay Colony?

Tags: colonial-america

I'm writing a historical fiction romance novel and I'm trying to gain a perspective of the travel times. The story is set in 1692, but the hero and his family arrived around 1680 from Ireland.

Answer (score 1):

As a ballpark number, the [Mayflower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayflower) took about 2 months to do a similar kind of trip a few decades earlier. By the end of the 17th century the trip would have been a bit faster ([about 6 weeks](https://www.quora.com/In-1767-how-long-did-it-take-to-get-to-London-from-New-York)) due to a better understanding of the prevailing winds and currents in the Atlantic.

Aside: there are a few other travel related questions on this site that you might want to look into. For instance: [How did passengers keep warm on sail ships?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52066/how-did-passengers-keep-warm-on-sail-ships) and [How long would it have taken to sail from Boston to Nova Scotia in 1775?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52475/how-long-would-it-have-taken-to-sail-from-boston-to-nova-scotia-in-1775)